# Remove line of text from file on ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a txt file with a series of strings on each line. I need to find for a given string, move that string to another file and remove that line from the file.

Moving to another file is working, this is the code.

```
File.open('file_moved.txt', 'w') { |file| file.puts pick_random_line.to_i.to_s }

def pick_random_line
  chosen_line = nil
  File.foreach("file.txt").each_with_index do |line, number|
  chosen_line = line if rand < 1.0/(number+1)
  end
  chosen_line
end
```

I'm a bit lost in how to remove the line from the other file. What would be the method in Ruby to remove the complete line with the matched string?

Comment: Depending on the size of the file I'd lean towards ingesting the whole file in memory (array of lines), manipulating the arrays and then writing the result back out. This file manipulation approach seems messy.

Comment: How big is `file.txt`?  The general workflow would be to open it, read it into memory, reopen it in write mode, write the array back except for your `chosen_line`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
lines = File.readlines('file.txt')

random_line = lines.shuffle.pop

File.open('file.txt', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(lines.join(''))
end

File.open('random.txt', 'a') do |f|
  f.write(random_line)
end
```

Note that `readlines` has the effect of reading the whole file into memory, but it also means you get a truly random sample from the file. Your implementation is probably biased more heavily toward the end of the file since you do not know how many lines there are in advance.

As with anything that does manipulation in this way, there is a small chance that the file might be truncated if this program is halted unexpectedly. The usual method to avoid this is to write to a temporary file, then rename when that's successful. A better alternative is to use a database, even an embedded one like SQLite.

Comment: maybe `lines.delete_at [rand % lines.count]`? Could cut expenses on shuffling and preserve line order :)

Also, `Tempfile` instance should be used for reading/writing, as you already mentioned.

Comment: @cdshines That is probably a more efficient method. Tempfile would work if you're careful to create it in the same directory. Some systems prohibit renaming of files across different filesystems.

Comment: Does this really remove the line from file.txt?

Answer (score 3):

Removing any bytes or substring from a file essentially means you must re-write the file from that point onwards at a minimum. Some specialist file system could maybe exist where that is not true, but most general-purpose file systems won't allow removing bytes from the middle of a file cheaply. Probably the closest you get to the "apply this change: delete these lines" type of control is a version management system like `git`.

That's really just philosophy as far as your problem is concerned though - if your output must be another text file with the line removed, then you simply generate two files:

- The new file with extracted data
- The altered original file with data removed (written back over the top of the original)

There are options for how you deal with the original file:

- Read all the data in, adjust in memory, and over-write the original. This is simplest, but doesn't scale to large files.
- Read data line by line, writing each line out immediately to either a temporary altered file, or the new file. At the end of the process, delete the original old file, and move the  temporary altered one into its place. This is a little more complex, but can handle larger files.

Comment: The second option is preferable. Line-by-line I/O is surprisingly fast. It's fast enough, based on many benchmarks I've done, for me to see no advantage to slurping a file into memory, especially after splitting the file is taken into account. There are several layers of buffering/caching that occurs before Ruby hands off a line to the code, so line I/O is basically coming from RAM as fast as the code can ask for it.